# Having an issue with changing a value of a text document

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to open a file called "rows.txt" and change the value to + 1 each time the code is ran.

```
exel_rows = open("Rows.txt", "r")

  exel_rows = exel_rows + 1

  exel_rows = str(exel_rows)

  saveFile = open('Rows.txt', 'w')
  saveFile.write(exel_rows)
  saveFile.close()
```

the error code is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Fletcher\Desktop\Bank.py", line 158, in <module>
    exel_rows = exel_rows + 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: '_io.TextIOWrapper' and 'int'
```

Comment: What is the content in the file ?

Comment: the content in the file is just the character "1"

Comment: Check my answer. It's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the you are adding a number to a string. So try the code below, `int()` will convert string to an integer.

Also You have to use `.read()` to read file data and store it in variable content.

```
  exel_rows = open("Rows.txt", "r")
  exel_rows = exel_rows.read();
  exel_rows = int(exel_rows) + 1
  exel_rows = str(exel_rows)
  saveFile = open('Rows.txt', 'w')
  saveFile.write(exel_rows)
  saveFile.close()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Fletcher\Desktop\Bank.py", line 156, in <module>
    exel_rows = int(exel_rows) + 1
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not '_io.TextIOWrapper'

Comment: @MarkIngram See my updated answer. You have to use `exel_rows.read();`

Comment: @MarkIngram Happy to help. Can you upvote my answer ? Someone have downvoted. i don't know why

Answer (score 1):

You should read the file content before adding the number:

Change:

```
exel_rows = open("Rows.txt", "r")
exel_rows = exel_rows + 1
```

to:

```
exel_rows = open("Rows.txt", "r").read()
exel_rows = int(exel_rows) + 1
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Fletcher\Desktop\Bank.py", line 155, in <module>
    exel_rows = int(exel_rows) + 1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Pretty sure the content of your `Rows.txt` isn't just a character `1` then.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you what's wrong:

1. `exel_rows` is of type `_io.TextIOWrapper`
2. `1` is of type `int`
3. Addition using the `+` operator isn't supported between these two types.

What the `open` function does is return a file object. You need to `read` your data from the file first.

```
file = open("Rows.txt", "r")
exel_rows = file.read()  # read the data from the file

print(exel_rows) # print the contents (for debugging purposes and whatnot)

exel_rows = int(exel_rows) + 1

# continue as normal
```

Comment: this creades the error code of:   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Fletcher\Desktop\Bank.py", line 158, in <module>
    exel_rows = int(exel_rows) + 1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: @MarkIngram
Hmm... that error message looks incomplete. Normally, it'd raise `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'xxx'`.
Can you try debugging the contents of your file?

Comment: the only contents that are in the file is the character "1"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the file name is `temp.txt`, that contains a value whose datatype is `str`, which can be casted into an `int`, you can do something like this:

```
f = open('temp.txt', 'r')   # Open the file in read Mode, to read the contents of the file.
f.seek(0)  # If something like 2324 is stored then place the place the cursor to the beginning
value = f.readlines()  # If the integer value spans over multiple lines (like 100 digit number, then read the whole line)
value = int(value[0]) + 1  # Update the value and store it back
f.close()  # close this instance 


f = open('temp.txt', 'w')  # reopen it in write mode to overwrite the existing contents.
f.write(str(value))  # place the results back into the file.
f.close()  # close this instance also.
```